# How does the debugger in eclipse helps in tracing bugs and fix them?

Tags: java, debugging

I'm a beginner in java, and I'm trying to understand how to use debugger in eclipse.
I know that it stops the program in a specific line and allows you to look at the variables,yet I don't understand how it helps to find bugs and correct them.
Can you give me simple examples where the code has bugs, and how the debugger helps with tracing them and fix them?

Comment: Not exactly the question for stackoverlfow, but it can be used to make sure that variables have the correct value and you don’t get incorrect values (hence meaning you made a mistake) for example if you do some math you might realize if it is wrong if you have a 3 instead of 5

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse debugger can be used to monitor variables and make sure that they hold the wanted value and you don’t get incorrect value.

For example, if you do some math you might realize if it is wrong if you have a 3 instead of 5.

This link might help: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html